# How would you implement the following in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React.

I want to make a result page containing list of products that will appear after the user types in their search criteria in a form and click submit on that form. Ideally, after the user clicks submit on the form, I want the form to dissappear and the result page to appear, listing all the searched products.

I have created the form, with a fetch function to send the form data to an api. The Api will send the results back, but since i want the results to be displayed in my created result page and make the form dissapear, what should I do here?

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented similar type of example for your. Please check it. **You need to put a number (for example 10)** and click the button to fetch question.

**QuestionSearch Component**

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import QuestionList from "./QuestionList";

export default class QuestionSearch extends React.Component {
    state = {
        amount: 0,
        isLoading: false,
        questions: [],
        error: null
    };

    textHandler = (e) =>{
        this.setState({amount: e.target.value})
    };

    fetchQuestions = () => {
        console.log(this.state);
        fetch(`https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=${this.state.amount}&difficulty=hard&type=boolean`,)
            .then(response => {
                    if (response.status !== 200) {
                        console.log('There was a problem. Status Code: ' + response.status);
                        return;
                    }
                    response.json().then(data => {
                        console.log(data);
                        this.setState({
                            questions: data.results,
                            isLoading: false
                        })
                    });
                }
            )
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log('Error: ', error);
                this.setState({error, isLoading: false})
            });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                amount (type 10 in textbox): <input id="amount" onChange={this.textHandler}/>
                <button onClick={this.fetchQuestions}>Click for calling API using fetch</button>
                {this.state.questions.length > 0 ?
                    <QuestionList data={this.state}/> : null
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**QuestionList Component**

```
import React, {Component} from "react";

export default class QuestionList extends React.Component {

    render() {
        const {isLoading, questions, error} = this.props.data;
        console.log(this.props, 'props');
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <h1>Random Question</h1>
                {error ? <p>{error.message}</p> : null}

                {!isLoading && questions ? (
                    questions.map((questionList, index) => {
                        const {question, category, type, difficulty} = questionList;
                        return (
                            <div key={index}>
                                <p>Question: {question}</p>
                                <p>Question Type: {type}</p>
                                <p>Difficulty: {difficulty}</p>
                                <hr/>
                            </div>
                        );
                    })
                ) : isLoading ? (
                    <h3>Loading...</h3>
                ) : null}
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```